# How to minify and concat javascript and css files in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pug

Is there a middleware that takes all public stuff like scripts, css, images, and fonts. And then losslessly compress them / minify, concat, replace their mention in templates with their calls. So script 1, script 2, script 3 tags let say in jade is replaced with all.concated.min.js and all images are merged into sprite sheet, losslessly compressed and then all their mentions of them in css or img tags is replaced by extra css rules that are also concated at the end of all.concat.min.css

i forgot to add that this **manager** should also handle http caching. As it's already replacing file values at server start. So it would make logo_s3kc.png max age infinity. But if logo changes which it keeps track using its own internal way, like using checksum. then it changes the name at next start of server so all files point to logo_new.png. but when i view file i only care about logo.png. Just like you have styles.less. Then there gets compiled styles.css etc.

Comment: There is a huge ecosystem of tools dealing with this. Please search on npmjs.com.

Comment: It's a madness to do things like that in *run time*, so I don't think that such *middleware* exists. Though, there is a plenty of building tools for node.js designed to do exactly the kind of things you mentioned.

Comment: no i want this to happen once at server start

Comment: Generally this would be done separately from starting the server. You could certainly have a script that does both, but having it be directly tied to starting the server isn't needed.

Comment: fair enough but running one more script before starting server is ok. But how

Comment: even in gruntjs i couldn't figure out spritesheet and infile replacement and it needs to be done with express to handle dynamic routing for caching purposes